# jquery dialog with zero to many child jquery dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a "parent" jQuery dialog that could span one to many jQuery dialogs when the OK button is pressed.    It also might not create any child dialogs.
I also want to take the user to a confirmation page when the OK button is pressed in the parent.

I have used the stack option in the child to get "stacked" dialogs to work.  My problem is when the OK button is pressed on the "parent", code continues to execute and the browser is taken to the confirmation page before the user has a chance to answer the "child" dialog.

Is there any way for the parent to wait till the child dialogs are answered before the code continues to take the user to the confirmation page from the parent's OK event?

My only other thought was to actually have the "child" OK button take the user to the confirmation page put that could complicate the code a bit since I would need code for letting the child know it is the last child so i can take the user to the confirmation page.

```js
function getDeclineReason(appName) {
  $("#dvDeclineReason")
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      stack: true,
      title: 'Decline Reason',

      open: function() {

        $('.ui-widget-content').css('background', 'white');
        $('.ui-widget-header').css('background', '#0072C6');
        $('.ui-widget-header').css('border', '1px solid #0072C6');
      },

      buttons: {
        OK: function() {

          $(this).dialog("close");
          return;

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          return;
        }
      },

      zIndex: 10000,
      autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto',
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,

    });

}



function reviewRequest() {
  getDeclineReason("Test");


  $("#dvReview")
    .dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: 'Review Request',


      open: function() {

        $('.ui-widget-content').css('background', 'white');
        $('.ui-widget-header').css('background', '#0072C6');
        $('.ui-widget-header').css('border', '1px solid #0072C6');
      },

      buttons: {
        OK: function() {


          var numChecked = 0;
          $('input[name="apps"]').each(function() {

            if (NWF$(this).is(':checked'))
              numChecked++;

          });


          if (numChecked == 0) {
            if (!confirm("You have not approved any applications.  If this was you intent then press OK to confirm the deny of all applications. Otherwise press cancel to try again."))
              return;
          }


          var totalApps = $('input[name="apps"]').length;
          var countApps = 0;

          $('input[name="apps"]').each(function() {

            var decision;

            if (NWF$(this).is(':checked'))
              decision = "Approved";
            else {
              decision = "Declined";
              getDeclineReason($(this).text());
            }


            switch (status) {
              case "Pend Mgr Review":
                updateFields["Title"] = "Manager Decision";
                break;

              case "Pend App Owner Review":
                updateFields["Title"] = "App Owner Decision";
                break;
            }

            countApps++;


            /*
                  
         updateFields["RequestNumber"] = requestNum;         
         updateFields["Application"] = $(this).text();   //  Get value from current check box item
         updateFields["AppStatusID"] = $(this).val();
         updateFields["Decision"] = decision;
         
         
         
         if (countApps == totalApps)
          updateFields["LastDecision"] = "Y";
         else
          updateFields["LastDecision"] = "N"; 
         
         
         addListItem("Decision",updateFields);                  
         */

          });



          $(this).dialog("close");
          //window.location.href = "/apps/TAI/SitePages/Decisioned.aspx";
          return;

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          return;
        }
      },


      zIndex: 10000,
      autoOpen: true,
      width: 'auto',
      resizable: false,
      draggable: false,

    });

}
```

Comment: Running the code snippet does nothing. And kindly use the option called "Tidy"!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of all the open dialogs and everytime the user clicks "OK" to close one of then substract one to the count and check if there are no more dialogs remaining. Then you can redirect the user to the other site.

Comment: Yes that is sort of what I mentioned.   But that really complicates things when in addition I am only getting one child dialog to pop up when in this case there should be 3.